# ¿Cómo calcular un total según lo seleccionado y mostrarlo?

Tags: javascript, html

Actualmente, tengo toda la estructura para seleccionar la opción en este caso son números del 1 al 100, y un `<input>` que muestra el valor principal de 1 *ticket*

¿Cómo puedo hacer para poder tomar el dato seleccionado y lo multiplique por `15000`, guardar el dato para usarlo y mostrarlo en el input?

```html
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit_compra'])){
    print_r($_POST);
}else{
    header('Location: '.$url.'formulario');
}


?>

        <section class="container_form">
            <div class="form">
                <h2>Selecciona la cantidad de ticket a comprar</h2>
                <form action="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Número de ticket">Número de ticket</label>
                        <select name="cantidad" class="form-control" id="">
                            <?php 

                                for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                                }
                                
                            ?>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombres">Valor a pagar</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="" value="" placeholder="$15.000" disabled>
                    </div>
                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-success btn-lg">Pagar ticket</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Te recomiendo asignar ID tanto al _select_ como al _input_, de forma que puedas acceder fácilmente con [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) y [asignar el evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) para calcular el total. Inténtalo y, si no funciona, edita la pregunta para agregar el código, solo así podemos tratar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para obtener los datos del `<select>` y usarlos utilice js para hacer el calculo y mostrarlo en el `input` y para tener un valor inicial y principal ejecuto ese `<script>` que le da el valor principal, con esto listo solo me falta poder obtener el numero entero del total a pagar, para utilizarlo en el pago.

```html
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit_compra'])){
    print_r($_POST);
}else{
    header('Location: '.$url.'formulario');
}



if (isset($_POST['submit_finalizar'])){
    print_r($_POST);
}
?>
<script>
  function inicio() {
    document.getElementById('sptotal').value = "$" + 15000;
  };
  window.onload = inicio;
</script>
<section class="container_form">
  <div class="form">
    <h2>Selecciona la cantidad de ticket a comprar</h2>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Número de ticket">Número de ticket</label>
        <select name="ticket" class="form-control" id="ticket" oninput="valTotal(this)">
          <?php 
                                for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sptotal">Valor a pagar</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sptotal" id="sptotal" placeholder="$15.000" readonly>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" name="submit_finalizar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-success btn-lg">Pagar ticket</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

ARCHIVO JS:

```js
function valTotal(ticket) {
  n_ticket = 1;
  n_ticket = ticket.value;
  document.getElementById('sptotal').value = "$" + n_ticket * 15000;
}
```